# Regular expression checking for two consecutive spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate the following condition:
Characters allowed, Max length of 5: **A-Z, 0-9, space and ('-**
and this is what I have got so far:

```
/^[a-zA-Z,\d,\-,\(,\']{1,5}$/;
```

How do I check for two consecutive spaces?

Comment: sorry something went wrong with the browser. Two consecutive spaces.

Comment: Are you trying to match two consecutive spaces *in addition to* what you have listed? Or just two consecutive spaces in general?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably match it again against `/\s\s/`.

Answer (score 6):

You can check for two consecutive spaces by using the repetition regex. 
i.e
If you want to match a regex which repeats say between 1 to 12 times, you can give,

```
regex{1, 12}
```

Similarly, if u want to match a space which repeats just two times and not more or less than that, you can give

```
\s{2}
```

Remember that this is a general way of checking the repeat patterns. The numbers in curly braces will always try to see the number of repetitions which the previous regex has.

cheers!

Comment: Note that `\s` does not just match against space. It will also match against tab, carriage-return, line-feed, or a few other weird white-space characters (vertical tab, for instance).

Comment: @JonahBishop Thanks for the info  :D Even I didn't know :D

Answer (score 3):

`\s{2}` is close, but `\s` matches many types of whitespace. ' {2}' (the pretty code format took away the space) works for me.

Answer (score 2):

So my assumption, you want to allow space characters, but want to disallow consecutive spaces (you don't make it clear in which way you want to check for them).

You could achieve this with a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*  )[a-zA-Z\d(' -]{1,5}$
```

Just add the space to the character class and use the zero width negative lookahead assertion to ensure that the expression will fail, if there are two consecutive space characters.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vptf)

Btw. I removed the commas from your character class most of the escaping and moved for that reason the hyphen to the end of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the commas in your regex, and they will cause it to misbehave. Write instead

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\-\(\']{1,5}$/
```

I'm not sure what you mean about two consecutive spaces, as it doesn't seem to apply to the rest of the question. A regex like `/  /` will match a pair of spaces, or `/\x20\x20/` or `/[ ][ ]/` to make them more visible.

Comment: Your second regex does not, in fact, match a pair of spaces; I only see one between the slashes. I might write it as: `/ {2}/`

Comment: That is why I suggested the alternatives. Believe me there are two spaces there - copy and paste the expression into an editor to see.

Comment: If a space is required `/\s/` cannot guarantee one because it matches CR, LF, FF, HT, and space

Answer (score 0):

This would be something you can use:

```
var string = "SD  D";

if (string.match(/^[A-Z\d\s\(\-']{1,5}$/)) {
    alert(string.match(/\s{2,}/) != null?"Has consecutive spaces of length 2+" : "Does not have consecutive spaces");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

/ {1,}/g

To replace two consecutive spaces to one space use this code:-
str.replace(/ {1,}/g, ' ');