# How to split line on the basis of 2 or more consecutive space?

Tags: java, string

I have a String like:

```
line = Microsoft SharePoint Workspace Audit Service  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\GROOVE.EXE";
```

I need to split above string in two parts like:

```
part1=Microsoft SharePoint Workspace Audit Service
part2="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\GROOVE.EXE"
```

This split is because there are two or more consecutive spaces between those parts.

How to do that?

Comment: Is there a logic involved here? or do you just want to split at the double quotes?

Comment: @ryadavilli - the question is how to split at 2 or more consecutive spaces

Comment: You could combine the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966884/regular-expression-checking-for-two-consecutive-spaces and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters to split based on regex representing two or more consecutive spaces

Comment: you can probably run a loop to check the maximum length of the spaces occuring continuously and with that length you can try splitting it just in the normal way

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] output = line.split("  ");
```

output[0] and output[1] is your answer

Comment: This will work for exactly two spaces, but the question refers to 'two *or more* consecutive spaces'

Comment: If suppose 3 spaces are there; still split will happen but we need to trim() on the values. To handle a case of 10 spaces; consider only those values which are not empty.

Comment: Why not add that to your answer to make it complete? :)

Comment: use `String[] split = line.split("  +");` for more than 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = "Microsoft SharePoint Workspace Audit Service  \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\GROOVE.EXE\"";

String[] parts = line.split("\\s{2,}");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
```

A good tutorial for using regular expressions in Java can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

You need regular expression for same.
Try following

```
String[] output = line.split("  +");
```

output[0] and output[1] is your answer

Answer (score 0):

String's method split() receives regex so you can use (for example):

```
String line = "Microsoft SharePoint Workspace Audit Service  \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\GROOVE.EXE\"";
String[] result = line.split("\\s{2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = line.split("\\s\\s+",2);
part1 = parts[0]; 
part2 = parts[1];
```

Above is working